# OpenSSL C#.NET wrapper, code source

Tags: c#, .net, openssl, wrapper

Can any one tell where can I find the OpenSSL .NET wrapper source code (http://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl-net/) ? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you emailed the project owner/maintainer?

Answer (score 2):

you almost had it...
http://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl-net/files/openssl-net/

Comment: i thought there is only "the openssl-net-0.4.4-win32", thx
So now if I modify a class in the wrapper or if I add any new class, can I generate a new DLL to import them in other projects ?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "Other versions" link on the page you reference, then click on the openssl-net link, then click on the 0.44 link, then click on the source link to download it.

Comment: i thought there is only "the openssl-net-0.4.4-win32", thx So now if I modify a class in the wrapper or if I add any new class, can I generate a new DLL to import them in other projects ?

Comment: @WolfSharp - Did you do as I said?  There is a link there for the source to download, as well as for the binary.  Yes, you can generate a new DLL if you want, or incorporate the classes directly in your code.  The code is licensed under the BSD so the license lets you do just about anything but claim it as your own.

Comment: yeah yeah of course, I did as you said ^^ thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 0):

The source code you are looking for has been moved to https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net